# Use of self.clients.claim() and self.skipWaiting() in service worker may increase the load time?

Tags: caching, service-worker, workbox

After reading many tutorials, I founded that `self.skipWaiting()` is used to immediately apply an update to an existing serviceWorker, and `self.clients.claim()` is used for taking control immediately on the first load.

```
self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
    event.waitUntil(self.skipWaiting());
});
self.addEventListener('activate', function(event) {
    event.waitUntil(self.clients.claim());
});
```

Is it lookup for update on every request or how does it work internally? Use of `self.clients.claim()` and `self.skipWaiting()` is any impact on load or service worker performance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no impact from a performance perspective.

Both [`self.skipWaiting()`](https://w3c.github.io/ServiceWorker/#service-worker-global-scope-skipwaiting) and [`self.clients.claim()`](https://w3c.github.io/ServiceWorker/#clients-claim) work by taking some action and, at the same time, immediately resolving with an `undefined` value.

In the case of `self.skipWaiting()`, the action that's taking is effectively just flipping an internal flag and causing the service worker to attempt to activate. In the case of `self.clients.claim()`, the action is to go through all the clients and attempt to have the currently executing service worker take control.

The actual promise that's returned by both of those methods is irrelevant, and you don't have to wrap them in `event.waitUntil()` (although it doesn't hurt, and many examples of service worker usage continue to do so).

Additionally, because your code is only making calls to those methods inside of `install` and `activate` listeners, the code in question won't even execute most of the time that the service worker thread starts up—only when there's an updated service worker.

Comment: This code will able to pick updates on first page refresh?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean—if you're looking for more info on the SW lifecycle, then https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/lifecycle is a great guide.